# PSQL stored procedures using arrays as parameter

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, loops, stored-procedures

I'm using PostgreSQL and currently creating a stored procedure to do some calculations. I've been searching all morning and reading the documentation, but either the functionality I want isn't supported or I must've overlooked something. Basically, this is what I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION predict_usage(preWaitTimes text, afterEndTimes text, targetIds text, drivingTime numeric, arrivalTime timestamp with time zone)
    RETURNS TABLE(
       target_id text,
       pre_wait_time numeric,
       after_end_time numeric,
       driving_time numeric,
       starting_time timestamp with time zone,
       ending_time timestamp with time zone
    )
DECLARE
    target_ids uuid[] := string_to_array(targetIds, ',')::uuid;
    pre_wait_times integer[] := string_to_array(preWaitTimes, ',')::integer[];
    after_end_times integer[] := string_to_array(afterEndTimes, ',')::integer[];
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(1, ceil(target.quantity/target.size)) as series,
END;
```

Basically what happens is that I calculate how often I need to make a travel to deliver something, which I use `generate_series` for. This works in a single SQL query, and I can use it to calculate how many drives I need to do to deliver it all, each with their own start and endtimes.

Now As different `targets` have different preparation and ending times (`preWaitTimes` and `afterEndTimes`), I would need to somehow connect the index of the `target_id` currently being used with the arrays of these additional times to make the calculations.

I've tried a `FOR` loop, but didn't manage to get it running. It also seems to me like the wrong path; I doubt that the DB can optimize FOR Loops that well, where I could just solve it on the java backend. The target is to do it in the DB for speed, mostly.

EDIT:

After thinking about it a bit more, maybe joining the 3 arrays into a table to begin *and then* do my calculations could work?

Comment: You shouldn't pass parameters using those dreaded comma separated values. They should be passed native arrays, declare your parameter, e.g. `targetIds text[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more documentation and searching, I've found the solution using `UNNEST`:

```sql
SELECT UNNEST(arr1::uuid[]) as id, UNNEST(arr2::text[]) as name, UNNEST(arr3::numeric[]) as value
...
```

**Attention:*

The created table has some limitation. For example, if the `id` is an `uuid[]` that uses the same ids that are `PK` in a table you want to join, it will somehow *not* do a hashed join. This can be circumvented with the following statement:

```
....
WHERE target_table.id = generated_table.id
    and target_table.id = any(arr1::uuid[])
```